# React.js simple route guard using Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

In a tutorial I have seen where the following route guard works and I have successfully put this into practice.

```
  if (!auth.uid) {
return <Redirect to='/sign_in' />
```

}

I was trying to run with this idea, but apply it to a specific email address (Ex. admin@gmail.com) Redirect everyone from this component except admin.

```
    if(email !== 'admin@gmail.com'){
      return <Redirect to='/'/>
}
```

I am referencing Google Firestore. I have access to auth via mapStateToProps. I believe I have everything "wired" up correctly. I think I am struggling with the JS logic?

See attached picture, I can successfully console log auth.email [image]

Comment: Where are you logging the value?

Comment: Put this where all your other routes are placed
`return email === 'admin@gmail.com' ? (<Route path={props.path} exact={props.exact} component={props.component} />) : 
        (<Redirect to="/" />);`

Comment: There are too many possible causes for this question to be answered well. Is `auth` populated asynchronously? You say you log `auth.email`, but your code only references `email`? Is this the problem or are there missing details? Please update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it can be answered, and it can be re-opened.

Comment: Another helpful tip: its always preferable to use text instead of images when possible. Sometimes its helpful, but most of the time plain text is easer to work with and read.